# How to find if the end of a string contains particular character

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Example A = Set "{Test}" to current time

I want to check if variable A have " at the end of the string.
I was thinking of using contains(), but then I do not know how to exactly look for the character " only at the end of the string regardless of the length of the String.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: XSLT uses XPath as its expression language, XSLT 1.0 XPath 1.0, so look at XPath 1.0 string functions (i.e. `substring` and `string-length`).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in XPath 1.0 is the clumsy test `substring($x, string-length($x)) = $quotation-mark`.

XPath 2.0 introduces `ends-with()` and regular expressions - time to move forward!